# Problem listening to Firebase Realtime Databse in Google Cloud

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, firebase-admin

I have my script in Python listening to a Firebase project by using the library `firebase_admin`. A minimal code example is:

The setup function:

```
def setup():
    '''Setup Harpia/Firebase comunication. 
        Return firebase app  
    '''

    credential = {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "-",
        "private_key_id": "-",
        "private_key": "-",
        "client_email": "-",
        "client_id": "-",
        "auth_uri": "-",
        "token_uri": "-",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "-",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "-"
    }

    cred = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(credential)
    return firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'storageBucket': '-',
        'databaseURL': '-',
        'httpTimeout': 10})
```

Where I omitted my information for obvious reasons. And the class that listen to the firebase is written below:

```
class FirebaseThread():
    '''Class that listen Database local (idname) 
    in firebase and check for changes in backgroud (Pebble Thread).'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''Initialize variables on default values.'''
        self.idname = None
        self.listening = False
        self.streaming = None

    @concurrent.thread()
    def start(self, idname):
        'Wait until the listening start.'
        self.idname = idname
        while not self.listening:
            try:
                # Events from firebase
                self.streaming = db.reference(
                    idname).listen(self.listenercallback)
                self.listening = True
                info('Conection started')
            except Exception as err:
                time.sleep(30)

    def close(self):
        if self.streaming is not None:
            self.streaming.close()

    def listenercallback(self, event):
        self.update()
```

and it works fine in my machine.

However, I created a VM in Google Cloud, in the very same project, and sent my script to it, but there it does not receive the changes in the database anymore.

I'm using the same credentials, and I can even send data to the firebase, I'm just not being updated by the changes in it.

Does anyone have a clue of what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to show a [complete minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), along with your debugging details.  Be sure to check for errors.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use the reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your exception handler isn't bothering to print anything that indicates what might have gone wrong.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for your awnser. I receive the message "Conection started", and I also have a print in the the listenercallback, the original code is way bigger but I put like this for readability. And still I never see the print from listenercallback

Comment: I'm saying you're not logging anything with `except Exception as err`.  What if an exception is thrown there?  You'd never know.  The code just sleeps.

Comment: The thing is, I'm always receiving the "Conection started" message, but to my surprise I deleted the VM and created a new one, and it worked like a charm!